# Does Affinity stack?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

I just completed my Azure Rathalos armor set, and noticed that it gave me an Affinity boost. I remembered that Nargacuga weapons also had an affinity boost. So before I start grinding for Nargacuga Dual Blades, I want to know, is it worth it? Or will Affinity not stack at all and I'll just have two different Affinity percentages?

Answer (score 3):

The Expert skill (from armour) stacks with the natural affinity percentage on weapons. For instance, I've used the Arko Nulo bow (5% affinity) with Diablos armour (Expert +1) which gives me an overall affinity of 15% on my status screen.

Comment: One thing to note, though, is that when upgrading weaponry, it will combine armor affinity with natural weapon affinity; will give misleading results.

Comment: @fbueckert did not know that. Thanks!